# Some equality from analysis book?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Can anyone prove the following claim ?

Assume that $u_1,u_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ are Schwartz functions. Prove that for any $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\xi\neq 0$ the following equality is satisfied:

$$\int_R\left|\int_{\xi_1 + \xi_2 = \xi} |\xi_1 - \xi_2|^{1/2} e^{it(\xi_1^3 + \xi_2^3)}u_1(\xi_1) u_2(\xi_2)\,d\xi_1\right|^2 \, dt = 
\frac{1}{|\xi|}\left(\int_{\xi_1 + \xi_2 = \xi} |u_1(\xi_1)|^2|u_2(\xi_2)|^2 \, d\xi_1+ 
\int_{\xi_1 + \xi_2 = \xi} u_1(\xi_1) \overline{u}_1(\xi_2) u_2(\xi_2) \overline{u}_2(\xi_1)\,d\xi_1\right).$$